In Playwright, how can I stop updating the HAR file after calling routeFromHAR()
We are using routeFromHAR(har, {update: true}) to record network traffic while testing an application that makes a series of REST calls (GETs and POSTs). I am doing the recording for the purposes of later running the tests offline using mocked data (i.e. {update: false}).
Question: is there an API in Playwright that STOPS the HAR file recording, so that I can start recording to a different HAR file?
More detail: let's say I start recording, and then do a GET and a POST to modify something in the database.  Like this pseudo-code:
1. page.routeFromHAR(har, {update: true});
2. oldData = GET('/foo');               // get initial data
3. POST('/foo', newData);               // update with new data
4. assert( GET('/foo') === newData) );  // get again; compare with new data

The problem happens when running later against the mocked HAR file (i.e. {update: false}).  The GET call in step (4) will return oldData and the test will fail.
I think what I want to do is spin up a new HAR file recording after step (3).  Like this:
1. page.routeFromHAR(har1, {update: true});
2. oldData = GET('/foo');               // get initial data
3. POST('/foo', newData);               // update with new data
4. page.routeFromHAR(har2, {update: true});
5. assert( GET('/foo') === newData) );  // get again; compare with new data

This way, I get two HAR files, and step (5) succeeds even when running offline against mocked data.
But ... when recording, even after starting har2 at line 4, the har1 file continues to record.  How can I STOP recording har1 before starting har2?  Calling page.unroute(har1) does not work.
